# print .mbox file with html content

Tags: printing, evolution, lp

I have to print an email for the district office.
I use `Evolution` as Email program and I can save the emails in `.mbox` format.

However when I save those email to a `.mbox` file and then do `lp example.mbox` it will print the email in an unreadable way.
It has `html` content, but I can't open the `.mbox` in `Firefox`.

Is there a way I can convert `.mbox` to `.pdf`?
Or can I tell the printer how to treat that file somehow?

I don't know how to render that html, it is correctly rendered in `Evolution`, but I can't print it from there because `Evolution` does not find my printers.

Comment: it's not evolution that looks for printers – you have a *printing system* that evolution uses. But: so, by the way, does `lp` usually. So, the solution here would really seem to fix that instead of trying to do something which you essentially need an email reader for  – reading an email and converting it to a visually useful format.

Comment: So, what does `lpstat -H` show? Please add that to your question. Please also add the output of `lpstat -s`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the issue by renaming the file from `.mbox` to `.html` and then going into `vim example.html` and deleting everything that doesn't belong to the `html`.
 Then I did `firefox example.html` and printed from there.

I wrote a small bash script that might help someone with the same problem, but I am not sure if this solution fits every `.mbox` file with `html` content.
You can probably also just use `lp example.html` instead of going into firefox and print from there.
The comments were leading into the right direction I guess.

```
#!/bin/bash

# call this script like this ./scriptname.sh yourfile.mbox

FILENAME=$(basename "$1")
FILENAMENOEXT="${FILENAME%.*}"
NEWFILE="${FILENAMENOEXT}.html"

# delete old output file if it already exists
if [ -f $NEWFILE ]; then
  rm $NEWFILE
fi


# cut out everything but html content

html_start_string="<!DOCTYPE HTML"

html_flag=0

while read line
do
  if [[ $line =~ $html_start_string ]]; then
    html_flag=1
  elif [[ $line =~ "--=" ]]; then
    html_flag=0
  fi
  if [ $html_flag -eq 1 ]; then
    printf "%s" "${line}" >> "${NEWFILE}"
  fi
done < $FILENAME

firefox $NEWFILE
```